# Need rounded corner for XSL-FO table?

Tags: xml, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am converting a XML data into PDF file with the help of XSL-FO template language, wanted a rounded corner for the header table and data table layout as shown below like
[image]

Right now I am getting only sharp corners have used `fox:border-radius` property also but doesn't work.

My XSL-FO:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.1"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
        xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
  <xsl:template match="root">
  <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page">
        <fo:region-body margin="1in"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>

    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block>Hello, <xsl:value-of select="name" />!</fo:block>
        <fo:block>
            <fo:table width="100%" fox:border-radius="4em" border=".125em solid #000000">
                 <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" 
            text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                        <fo:block>
                            No.
                            </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" 
            text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                        <fo:block>
                            Name
                            </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" 
            text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                        <fo:block>
                            Phone Number
                            </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                  </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
              </fo:table>
              <fo:table width="100%" fox:border-radius="4em" border=".125em solid #000000">
              <fo:table-body>    
                  <xsl:for-each select="./friend">
                    <xsl:for-each select="./closefriends">
                    <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
                            </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="../name" />
                          <xsl:value-of select="names" />
                            </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="phNo" />
                            </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                  </fo:table-row>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                 </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
  </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't know, what I am missing here to achieve the rounded borders for table.

Comment: One thing that is missing from your stylesheet is a declaration of the `fox` namespace prefix, bound to `http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions`.

Comment: I tried this options too, but it is not working...

Comment: "Rounded corners on tables are not directly supported. To set rounded corners at the table level the table must have the property border-collapse property set to separate" (http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/extensions.html#rounded-corners)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that you must fix in order to produce rounded corners on tables with FOP:

- Add a declaration of the `fox` namespace prefix, bound to `http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions` (see http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/extensions.html#fox-namespace).
- Set the value of the `border-collapse` property to "separate" (see http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/extensions.html#rounded-corners).